# Were condemned prisoners drugged prior to execution?

Tags: halacha, history, capital-punishment

According to [this unsubstantiated Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_and_corporal_punishment_in_Judaism#The_four_types_of_capital_punishment), criminals condemned to death by Beith Din were drugged and rendered senseless prior to being executed.

Is this factually correct (either Halachically or historically)?

Comment: doesn't the gemarah say that if a man is going out to be executed and says to write and give a bill of divorce to his wife it is binding? if he was senseless this would not be the case

Comment: @nikmasi, he could be drugged afterward.

Comment: @Nikmasi, that could have been before he was drugged; more likely, that's discussing a case of someone being taken out for execution by the Greeks or Romans, not Jews!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sanhedrin 43a:

> אמר רב חסדא היוצא ליהרג משקין אותו קורט של לבונה בכוס של יין כדי שתטרף דעתו שנאמר (משלי לא) תנו שכר לאובד ויין למרי נפש
>
> Said Rav Chisda: One being taken out to be executed, we give him a drink of a dose of frankincense dissolved in a cup of wine, to discombobulate his mind. As the verse (Proverbs 31) says, "give strong drink to one who is lost, and wine to the bitter of soul."

I don't think it was drugged to the point of unconsciousness, but some type of sedation.

Comment: I had always wondered how to translate discombobulate into Hebrew.